# Error in the Fixest package in R when running feglm with instruments

Tags: r

I am running the feglm regression with instruments and I get the following error

```sh
Error in feglm(total_crimes ~ rh + temp | station + hour + weekday + month_year_station |  : 
  The left hand side (total_crimes ~ rh + temp | station + hour + weekday + month_year_station | pm25_n) is not numeric. The class formula is not supported.
```

I am using the formula like:

```r
feglm(Dependent  ~ exog_1 + exog_2 |fe_1 + fe_2| endog_1 ~ IV , data = y, family = "poisson")
```

Naturally, I double checked that my endogenous and IV variables were numeric.

**For reproduction of the error:** The same error occurs with the Trade data set that comes with the package when trying to run a simple IV like:

```
feols(Euros ~ 1 | dist_km ~ product, data = trade)
```

Comment: Two comments: a) it looks like the version of the package is not the one in which IVs have been implemented, could you write which version you use? b) in the trade data set, the variable name is Product (with upper case P), otherwise the misspelling would lead to an error different from the question.

Comment: Generally with non-linear models, the preferred method is to use a control function approach (rather than IV-2SLS): https://statistics.rutgers.edu/home/zijguo/Guo-Small-Control%20Function%20Estimation%20of%20Nonlinear%20Causal%20Effect%20Models.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, instrumental variables have been implemented only for OLS and not for non-linear models. So, unfortunately, there's no way around it.

Note that the error is:

```
 fepois(Euros ~ 1 | dist_km ~ Product, data = trade)
#> Error in fepois(Euros ~ 1 | dist_km ~ Product, data = trade) : 
#>   The RHS of the formula must represent the fixed-effects (and can't be equal to
#>     a formula: only feols supports this).
```

the fact that GLM models do not accept IVs is stated in parentheses in the error message (although the message could have been clearer).